# NSFetchedResultController refresh table view too slow

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am writing an IM app by storing the conversation list in the Core Data, and display the data source via `NSFetchedResultsController`. The Core Data stack is copied from Apple's example code.

The `NSFetchedResultsController` is initialized as follows:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (!_fetchedResultsController) {
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[IMWrapper sharedInstance].chatManager managedObjectContext];
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [Conversation entityInManagedObjectContext:context];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:ConversationAttributes.lastTime ascending:NO];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

        // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
        // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
        NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
        aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
        _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![_fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

When a message is received, I will update the unread count of the corresponding conversation which is stored in Core Data, and refresh the badge number on both the conversation and the corresponding tab bar item. However, the tab bar item's badge number is updated immediately, while the conversation's badge number is updated several seconds later. I am afraid that the `NSFetchedResultsController` does not fetch the new unread count in time. Following code shows my methods of `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`.

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

I hope anyone could help me. Thank you very much!

P.S. I searched in stack overflow, someone says it might be the thread problem. I print the thread information in didChangeObject method, and find that it is not in the main thread. Some answer tells to merge the update in moc to main thread. But I don't know how to.

The following code shows the update for the unread message count. The problem might lie there.

```
dispatch_async(self.messageQueue, ^{
    // Update unreadMessageCount here
    if (aMessage.isRead == NO) {
        // mogenerator provides this convenient method.
        self.unreadMessageCountValue += 1;
    }

    NSError *updateError = nil;
    if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&updateError]) {
        DLog(@"Unable to update managed object context.");
        DLog(@"%@, %@", updateError, updateError.localizedDescription);
    }

    // Add aMessage to message array....

    // Update tab tar badges via chat manager....
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't call `[self.tableView reloadData]` after [`self.tableView endUpdates]`. It's not needed as the data in table view is already reloaded (by inserting / deleting / reloading rows in `controller:didChangeObject:...` method. As for your question, please show the code in which you set the conversation's badge number.

Comment: Take a look at the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the line of code telling the table view to refresh a row when its corresponding managed object has changed.  To the following method:

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
   atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
  newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
```

Add the missing line, as follows:

```
       case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self.savedLocsTable reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
```

That may be all that's needed.  So, when the Conversation's unreadCount changes and is saved to Core Data, this method is called with NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate and the corresponding table row will now be reloaded.

---

UPDATE

After seeing your code to update the message count, I think you do have a threading problem.

If you did, indeed, copy the Core Data stack from Apple's example, you only have 1 moc and it is on the main thread.  So, all you need to do is return to the main thread to modify any managed objects or do any work on the moc.  (Note that neither moc's nor managed objects are threadsafe.  If you create them on the main thread, you can only modify them on the main thread.)

Also, I noticed that you are updating the tab bar in the background thread.  You may also want to move this to the main thread.  (AFAIK, most interactions with UIKit must be done on the main thread, with the exception of UIImage, UIColor, UIFont and Core Graphics, which are all threadsafe.  However, it's possible that in newer versions of iOS modifying a tab bar is threadsafe, and your program seems to be working well in that area.  So, proceed with caution.)

Here is the code to return to the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(self.messageQueue, ^{
    if (aMessage.isRead == NO) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Update unread message count here
            // mogenerator provides this convenient method.
            self.unreadMessageCountValue += 1;

            NSError *updateError = nil;
            if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&updateError]) {
                DLog(@"Unable to update managed object context.");
                DLog(@"%@, %@", updateError, updateError.localizedDescription);
            }
        });

        // Add aMessage to message array....

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Update tab bar badges (unless chat manager stuff must be done in messageQueue and cannot be separated from tab bar stuff)
        });

    }
});
```

So, both changes are needed: (1) handle NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate as shown above and (2) make any changes to a NSManagedObject or to the moc ONLY on the main thread.

Comment: I followed your instruction, but the reload is too slow. However, if I scroll the table or change to other tab and change back, it shows the updated information immediately. I am driven mad for such behavior of NSFetchedResultsController.

Comment: Is the table view in edit mode when the unreadCount is updated?  While the user is editing the table, the NSFetchedResultsController will not report changes to the delegate immediately, and the table must be updated manually.

Comment: No, the table view is in normal mode. I searched in stack overflow, someone says it might be the thread problem. I print the thread information in `didChangeObject` method, and find that it is not in the main thread. Some answer tells to merge the update in moc to main thread. But I don't know how to.

Comment: Yes, if you have 2 moc's, one in a background thread and one in the main thread, you would have to merge the update to the main thread.  I'm not sure exactly how to do that, but it has become much easier in newer versions of iOS.  However, make sure you do need a background moc.  You may be better off with only 1 moc, in the main thread.  And, if you did not set up a background moc, that is not the problem.

Comment: Can you show the code where you update the unread count?  The problem may be there.

Comment: Thank you very much. I solved the problem via your solution. Yes, it is the thread problem.